# No-Sql and Asp.net Mvc

Tags: asp.net, data-structures, nosql, redis

i asked a related question like this but it was deleted so i have filtered it out

I am creating a twitter like app where feeds are generated for each activity and subscribers can see those feeds.

Currently iam using sql and joining + unioning (union command) too many tables, I have read many places that for feeds like structure NoSQL ([redis](http://redis.io/) or some other) is used.

I am looking for a hello-world sort of application for that in ASP.NET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check RavenDb http://ravendb.net/ there is a Demo of the MVC Music Store

RavenDb https://github.com/ravendb/ravendb is mantained primarly (I think) by http://ayende.com/blog that has made a lot of cool tools for the .NET community...

And for the twitter REST, I've used http://hammock.codeplex.com/ (it seems that they are not anymore in codeplex....)

http://www.ohloh.net/p/hammock

Answer (score 2):

> I am creating a twitter like app where feeds are generated for each
>   activity and subscribers can see those feeds.

It looks like a good use case for redis [pub/sub](http://redis.io/topics/pubsub).

> I am looking for a hello-world sort of application for that in
>   ASP.NET.

[ServiceStack](https://github.com/ServiceStack), which is a maintainer of [C# redis client](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis), have some [examples](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Examples).

Answer (score 1):

There are no differences using SQL databases and NoSql databases (like [RavenDB](http://ravendb.net/)) with ASP.NET MVC. Just choose one of them, according to your requirements, and use its API.